# Django annotate sum subquery

Tags: python, django

How to sum a field of a subquery ( with OuterRef ) and annotate it on outer model?

note that I have a common `my_special_queryset_annotator` that alter queryset by adding some annotations, ... so i dont want to use direct `Sum('books__sections__page')`

let assume following models

```py
class Library(models.Model):
    votes=models.IntegerField()

class Book(models.Model):
    library=models.ForiegnKey(Library)

class Section(models.Model):
    book=models.ForiegnKey(Book)
    pages=models.IntegerField()

# this works, but when want to use `my_special_queryset_annotator` 
# we could not do this simple annotation
Library.annotate(
    all_pages=Sum('books__sections__pages'),
)

# when want to sum on a Subquery, its must constructed like below but it dont work
Library.objects.annotate(
    all_pages=SUM(  # <-- problem
        Subquery(
            my_special_queryset_annotator(
                Section.objects.filter(book__libraray_id=OuterRef('id'))
            ).values('altered_pages')
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: The `Sum` should be inside the subquery, as shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#using-aggregates-within-a-subquery-expression)

Comment: So: `all_pages=Subquery(qs.annotate(total_pages=Sum('pages')).values('total_pages')[:1])`

Comment: i have tested this before and this is not working correct, specially with OuterRef, it return only first section pages as all_pages.

Answer (score 5):

one try that solve the problem in ugly way is to create something like below, but i cant configure how not to pass `sum_field` parameter to it and just use `.values(sum_field)` on given queryset

```py
class SumSubquery(Subquery):
    template = "(SELECT SUM(%(sum_field)s) FROM (%(subquery)s) _sum)"
    output_field = models.DecimalField()

    def __init__(self, queryset, output_field=None, *, sum_field, **extra):
        extra['sum_field'] = sum_field
        super(SumSubquery, self).__init__(queryset, output_field, **extra)
```

```py
# and use like below

Library.objects.annotate(
    all_pages=SumSubquery(
        my_special_queryset_annotator(
            Section.objects.filter(book__libraray_id=OuterRef('id'))
        ),
        sum_field='altered_pages',
    )
)
```